# Create custom page with React code in NextJS + Prismic project

Tags: reactjs, next.js, prismic

I'm a relative beginner with NextJS. I recently used [this starter template](https://github.com/prismicio-community/nextjs-starter-prismic-blog) to start my blog from. Everything works as it should (when I add an article or a page in Prismic, it gets created on my site and is visible).

My question is that I would like to add a new page to my website that is *not* Prismic-based. In essence, I built a small calculator tool in React, and I want to add it to my site, to make it discoverable on, e.g. [www.mywebsite.com/tool](http://www.mywebsite.com/tool). However, I don't see how that is possible with the current setup. You can see the folder structure below - when I create a new page in Prismic, it gets automatically fetched by the NextJS code with [uid]. When I add a new article, I can see in on my website because of articles/[uid]. This means that all articles have the same layout, and all non-article pages have the same layout.

But how can I create a page that shows up on my site as all the other pages ([www.mywebsite.com/tool](http://www.mywebsite.com/tool)), but does not follow the regular structure?

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBC7D.png)

I tried a bunch of things! Adding the page direcly to the app directory, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To add a static page to a Next.js app, add a directory in the `app` directory named after the route. In that directory, create a `page.tsx` file containing the page's components and metadata.

For example, you can create a route at `/tool` by creating a file at `app/tool/page.tsx` with the following contents:

```
// app/tool/page.tsx

export default function Page() {
  return <div>My tool page</div>
}
```

See the [Next.js Page documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#pages) for details how to write a `page.tsx` file.

To avoid conflicts with your static `/tool` route and your Prismic pages, do not create a Prismic page with a UID of `tool`.